# Add/delete a value from hashmap onClick of a button

Tags: android

I want to update the listView when user adds a value... 
I used SimpleAdapter and hashmap
But shows only one value when add button is clicked.
When I enter a value again and press the add button, ListView does not show it!
Please help....

Comment: Post some code to identify the problem.

Comment: Try cid's answer. That would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a missing :

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is not there.... I'm using list adapter. That function is not there... Only notify() and notifyAll() is shown

Comment: "list adapter", you mean SimpleAdapter? That's because SimpleAdapter is intended to be used only for _static_ data. Try to use another adapter, like ArrayAdapter for example.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added or deleted a value from the hashmap associated with your list adapter, call:

> adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

If its still not updating, check this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5092426/2219600)

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); is not there.... I'm using list adapter. That function is not there... Only notify() and notifyAll() is shown